# Unity 4.3.4 Crashes on Load (Android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm getting a crash when I run my game on Unity for Android.  Unity Version 4.3.4 on a Windows 7 64 Bit Machine with a Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3).  Here is a dumb filtered for Unity (I have know idea why this is happening):

```
D/Unity   (26387): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
D/Unity   (26387): Loading /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   (26387): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll (this message is harmless)
D/Unity   (26387): Loading /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   (26387): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
D/Unity   (26387): Loading /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   (26387): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll (this message is harmless)
D/Unity   (26387): Loading /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   (26387): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll (this message is harmless)
D/Unity   (26387): Loading /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   (26387): - Completed reload, in  0.178 seconds
D/Unity   (26387): PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK
D/Unity   (26387): Found 19 native sensors
D/Unity   (26387): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.009577 / 0.01s ; LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer / STMicroelectronics 

D/Unity   (26387): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.009577 / 0.01s ; LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer / STMicroelectronics 

D/Unity   (26387): WARNING: DXT texture format is not supported, decompressing texture

D/Unity   (26387): WARNING: DXT texture format is not supported, decompressing texture

D/Unity   (26387): WARNING: DXT texture format is not supported, decompressing texture

D/Unity   (26387): WARNING: DXT texture format is not supported, decompressing texture

D/Unity   (26387): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)

D/Unity   (26387): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.009577 / 0.01s ; LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer / STMicroelectronics 

E/Unity   (26387): Profiler is only supported in Unity Pro.

E/Unity   (26387):  

E/Unity   (26387): (Filename: Runtime/Profiler/ProfilerImpl.cpp Line: 560)

E/Unity   (26387): 

I/Unity   (26387): setScreenSize: -1x-1 (1280x720 / 1280x720)

I/Unity   (26387): setScreenSize: keeping layout size 1280x720

I/ActivityManager( 2350): Config changes=480 {1 1 1.0 302mcc610mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w360dp h615dp 320dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.45}

W/ActivityManager( 2350): mDVFSHelper.acquire()

W/ActivityManager( 2350): mDVFSHelper.release()

I/Unity   (26387): onPause

D/Unity   (26387): UnloadTime: 13.945999 ms

D/Unity   (26387): System memory in use before: 32.8 MB.

D/Unity   (26387): Unloading 3 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0 / Dirty serialized files: 0)

D/Unity   (26387): System memory in use after: 31.5 MB.

D/Unity   (26387): 

D/Unity   (26387): Unloading 2 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 781.

D/Unity   (26387): Total: 3.838000 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.217000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.054000 ms MarkObjects: 2.576000 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.228000 ms)

D/Unity   (26387): 

D/Unity   (26387): Waiting for finish

D/Unity   (26387): ASensorManager_destroyEventQueue returned 0

I/Unity   (26387): windowFocusChanged: false

I/Unity   (26387): onDestroy

I/ActivityManager( 2350): Process com.FreelanceGames.DERPofDUTY (pid 26387) (adj 9) has died.
```

Comment: At least format your code...

Comment: `E/Unity   (26387): Profiler is only supported in Unity Pro.` seems like you might have the wrong license for what you are doing?!